# Memory leak with Firebase Android PhoneAuthProvider

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

Firebase -> PhoneAuthProvider -> VerifyPhoneNumber is leaking. I believe, it might be OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks, which we are sending on call to verifyPhoneNumber.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Launch the app
2. Select "PhoneAuthActivity" for phone based authentication
3. Send Phone Number.
4. Click back.

When clicking back, the leaked memory appear

Does someone have the same problem? any solution?

```
public void FirebasePhoneUser(String phoneNumber) {
            mCallback = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                    Log.d("Completed","");
                }
                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                    Log.d("Error","");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                  PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    Log.d("onCodeSent", "");
                }
            };
            phoneAuthProvider = PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance();
            phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
                    phoneNumber,
                    30,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
                    mCallback
            );
}
```

Comment: Did you discover this with LeakCanary, or what?  I don't know the solution, I just want to make sure you've correctly identified the problem.

Comment: yep, with LeakCanary

Comment: If you observe an obvious problem with Firebase SDKs, please file a bug report with Firebase support so they can try to reproduce it and collect information.  There's not much Stack Overflow can do with this.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: There is a similar question started in 2017 and without a solution. That's why I wrote it here.

Comment: This is not very clear unfortunately. Keep in mind that just because memory stays allocated after the activity ran does not mean there's a leak, as there is likely a change in state (and a change in memory usage) because of the call to verify the phone number. What type of memory do you think is being leaked? How do you think it's being leaked? What do you think should be done to remove the leak?

Comment: okay, I started by deactivating the Leak Canary and running the application with the android studio Profiler tool (shows the memory consumption of the application). I recreated the event where the memory leak occurred, sending the phone and returning to the previous activity many times and although there is an increase in memory progressively, but I could not assure that it comes exclusively from verifyphonenumber (firebase).

Comment: Even so, when activating the Leak Canary, the memory leak appears, which makes me think that the listening method is running. Unlike FirebaseAuth, which is quite complete and has the .removeAuthStateListener () method, PhoneAuthProvider does not have a similar method.

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Given that API is terrible and there's no option to unsubscribe, you have several options to work this around.

1. Proxy or Decorator. You create another `OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks` which delegates method calls to another instance:

```java
// this class must be either top-level or 'static'!
public /*static*/ final class DelegatingVerificationStateCallbacks
    extends PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    implements Closeable {
    @Nullable private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks delegate;
    public DelegatingVerificationStateCallbacks(
        @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks delegate
    ) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override public void onCodeSent(
        @NonNull String verificationId,
        @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken
    ) {
        if (delegate != null) delegate.onCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
    }
    @Override public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(@NonNull String s) {
        if (delegate != null) delegate.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
    }
    @Override public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        if (delegate != null) delegate.onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential);
    }
    @Override public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
        if (delegate != null) delegate.onVerificationFailed(e);
    }

    @Override public void close() {
        delegate = null;
    }
}
```

I've implemented `Closeable` for cleanup but you could implement RxJava's `Disposable` or whatever instead.

The usage pattern here is obvious and well-known:

```java
public final class SomeScreen extends ActivityOrFragmentOrControllerOrWhatever {
    private final ArrayList<Closeable> disposeBag = new ArrayList<>();
    private void performAuth() {
        DelegatingVerificationStateCallbacks callbacks =
            new DelegatingVerificationStateCallbacks(
                new OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() { … }
            );
        disposeBag.add(callbacks);
        phoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(…, callbacks);
    }
    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        for (Closeable c : disposeBag) {
            try { c.close(); }
            catch (IOException ignored) { }
        }
        disposeBag.clear();
    }
}
```

Result: Firebase leaks a reference to empty and cheap `DelegatingVerificationStateCallbacks`, not to Activity.

2. Nulling references out yourself. You can take approach presented above to clear your own references to Activity. This implies these reference must be explicit, i. e. class must not be anonymous or inner to your activity. You must take full control of class constructor and fields, top-level class or nested `static` class is a good fit.
3. Weak reference. This is less explicit and involves some indirection but still works: you instantiate top-level or nested `static` class, pass Activity to constructor, wrap it in a WeakReference, and assign to a field. That's all, after some time `WeakReference#get` will start returning `null`.
4. Reflection. Very bad and unstable option which could help in some other situations. Sometimes your Activity could be leaked by Android SDK or vendor-specific code, and options from above don't apply. Then you can null out some private fields yourself. Don't do this for Firebase.